# Twilio pull SMS message logs by status

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is it possible to pull only message logs with a status of Undelivered via the API? Trying to pull a full months worth of logs and iterating over everything takes a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list-get it looks like you can only filter by `To`, `From` and `DateSent`.

Eg.

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages?To=12345678901
```

I agree that being able to filter by `Status` would be very useful.

Comment: That is what I found as well but thought maybe I was missing something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andy, you're spot on. We don't have any other filtering in the API, so you will have to pull all the messages (to make fewer requests, use `PageSize` to get 1000 messages at a time) and filter on your end. (disclosure: I'm a developer evangelist at Twilio :) )